# Migration with double db files on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

[image]when I try to continue with my project, I am not sure when I create two DB almost with the same, I am watching a tutorial but he just have the one that have "change" the other one with "self" is never mentioned, and now I am having trouble because the webpage says that I have one table pending to migrate and if I try to migrate with the terminal, it says me that it could not be migrated because

```
$ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20210220193851 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/railsfriends/crypto/db/migrate/20210220193851_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and the same error with the column "email" if I try $ rails db:migrate

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more in depth what you want to achieve with the two DB you mentioned? I see in the log output that you are trying to run a migration that adds `email` column to the `users` table, but it already exists. Could it be that you are trying to add devise to an existing project where `users` table already has some of the columns that devise requires and that causes conflict?

Comment: Hi, I think that´s just my error, I am not sure when or how I created another table (the one with "self" things . I just edited my post, showing the pic of the 2 DB. And I cant delete it, if I try with some codes, the terminal says that I dont have permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, these two files are database migration files and meant to change the database structure. [Here you can check out the official guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for further details on how they work.

The problem is that you are trying to do the same modifications to the DB two times. The first time the `devise_create_users` migration is run, it creates a `users` table with columns `email`, `encrypted_password` and so on. Then the second file, the `add_devise_to_users` is run that tries to modify the `users` table by adding the same columns (`email`, `encrypted_password`, etc.). The former is for adding devise to a new project where no user model exists yet, while the latter is for adding devise to an already existing user.

To solve this issue you just have to remove the second migration file `add_devise_to_users` as it is not necessary in your case.

Comment: thank  you so mucho, it confirms what I though, but do you know what could I do if, when I try to delete it with drop, but it sent me an error, because I did not have permission. I got so frustrated that I reapeted my project, but it could be nice to know how to do it. I tried to erease it manually and (with sublime) the folders of DB put like a red advice that something was wrong.